# How to get fileList by Dropbox?

Tags: jsp, dropbox, filelist

I have a question. but I do not speak English well. Please understand.

I got the `access token` from the Dropbox. and I want a list of files.

I could not find the [Dropbox Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares).
Please tell us how to get a list of files.

======================================================================

gpgekko// I've been told you have to find metadata does not have the desired result.

This URL is for importing metadata.

```
https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/<root>/<path>
```

`/<root>/<path>` exclusion did not know what it is.

JSP file, this function is called.

```
public void getFiles() throws IOException {
    consoleCheck("getFiles");

    String parameters = "access_token=" + access_token;
    parameters += "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri;
    parameters += "&list=true";
    URL url = new URL("https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    writer.writeBytes(parameters);
    writer.flush();

    if (writer != null)
        writer.close();

    InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
        stringBuffer.append('\r');
    }
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(stringBuffer.toString());
    System.out.println("object => " + object);
}
```

Comment: Look at the [`metadata`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata) endpoint. I think this is the one you need.

Comment: gpgekko, thank you. I will try as your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in this way.

I remove `redirect_uri` in parameter and add `/dropbox/` in end of url

```
public JSONObject getFiles() throws IOException {
    consoleCheck("getFiles");

    String parameters = "access_token=" + access_token;
    //parameters += "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri;
    parameters += "&list=true";
    URL url = new URL("https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    writer.writeBytes(parameters);
    writer.flush();

    if (writer != null)
        writer.close();

    InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
        stringBuffer.append('\r');
    }
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(stringBuffer.toString());
    //System.out.println("object => " + object);
    return object;
}
```

result type is JSONObejct. and result value is like this.

```
{
"size": "0 bytes",
"hash": "37eb1ba1849d4b0fb0b28caf7ef3af52",
"bytes": 0,
"thumb_exists": false,
"rev": "714f029684fe",
"modified": "Wed, 27 Apr 2011 22:18:51 +0000",
"path": "/Public",
"is_dir": true,
"icon": "folder_public",
"root": "dropbox",
"contents": [
    {
        "size": "0 bytes",
        "rev": "35c1f029684fe",
        "thumb_exists": false,
        "bytes": 0,
        "modified": "Mon, 18 Jul 2011 20:13:43 +0000",
        "client_mtime": "Wed, 20 Apr 2011 16:20:19 +0000",
        "path": "/Public/latest.txt",
        "is_dir": false,
        "icon": "page_white_text",
        "root": "dropbox",
        "mime_type": "text/plain",
        "revision": 220191
    }
],
"revision": 29007
}
```

thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Having tagged your question as "java" I suggest you try and follow their tutorial [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java). In particular when *Listing Folders* - they use [DbxClient.getMetadataWithChildren()](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#getMetadataWithChildren%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I'm sorry if there was error. I will use JSP Java is not. Question tags are fixed.